# Problem pulling a Docker image from Docker Hub

Tags: image, manifest, artifactory, pull

If I run the 'docker pull' command to pull an image directly from docker hub, it works fine.

But when I pull the image via Artifactory, i.e. with docker hub as the remote repository, then I got this error:

Error response from daemon: manifest for //image1:1.0.0 not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry.

Another note is, if the image doesn't have the "image path", it works fine.

What is going wrong here?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: what image path? Can you elaborate on how Artifactory is connected with Docker? What docker access method is being used? Is there are reverse proxy (Nginx) on top of Artifactory? What is the exact docker pull command? Were any errors seen in the Artifactory logs for the image?

Comment: Here is an example that is not working, where I receive that error:  docker pull myartifactory.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-keycloak:latest - you see here, there is the 'rapidminer' layer there.  There's is a reverse proxy on top of Artifactory - Apache httpd.  There's no error in Artifactory logs.

Comment: so it seems like you are using the docker sub-domain [https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-TheSubdomainMethod] method and it is failing. Can you check the HTTPD logs by grepping the image name and see if the request somewhat failing? or does Artifactory received the request by grepping the artifactory logs for the image name.

Comment: It does show the image in the log:: 2021-08-26 18:23:03,295 [http-nio-8081-exec-7747] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.r.v.DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:110) - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'radpidminer/rapidminer-grafana' and tag '9.9.0'

Comment: Any other errors seens? This is an INFO message where Artifactory is trying to get the manifest. Also, is the issue happens for all images or a specific one?

Comment: I don't see other errors.  This issue apply to any images (and now even without the 'layer' described above).

Comment: can you share the reverse proxy config as well as the docker access method in HTTP settings page from Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe repo is empty. Check on dockerhub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm this is the case with me! I download an image somewhere and planned to use it in my cluster but realized that I have load the image and tagged it but I did not push it to the cluster registry. Thanks